# How to group json array and sum its total per week?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json

I have an array

```
    [
        {
            "week_year": "49-2021",
            "total": 6.5
        },
        {
            "week_year": "45-2021",
            "total": 28.5
        },
        {
            "week_year": "45-2021",
            "total": 6.5
        },
        {
            "week_year": "44-2021",
            "total": 6.5
        },
        {
            "week_year": "46-2021",
            "total": 14.5
        }
    ]
```

I want to group it by the same week_year and sum its total per week. Any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output needed is like `{ week_year => total }` then you can use a combination of [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum):

```
arr
  .group_by { |hash| hash[:week_year] }
  .transform_values { |arr| arr.sum { |hash| hash[:total] } }
# {"49-2021"=>6.5, "45-2021"=>35.0, "44-2021"=>6.5, "46-2021"=>14.5}
```

Comment: I was 4 seconds too late :D

Comment: never too late for the party

Answer (score 1):

If `arr` is the array given in the question one could write

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:week_year]] += g[:total] }
  #=> {"49-2021"=>6.5, "45-2021"=>35.0, "44-2021"=>6.5, "46-2021"=>14.5}
```

This makes a single pass through the array and requires less memory than does the use of `Enumerable#group_by`. Arguably, it also reads better. Whether it's faster is an open question.

This employs the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument--called the *default value*--and no block. If a hash `h` is so-defined, then, possibly after keys have been added, if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value. The default value is commonly chosen to be zero, as it is here.

The expression

```
h[g[:week_year]] += g[:total]
```

expands to

```
h[g[:week_year]] = h[g[:week_year]] + g[:total]
```

so if `h` does not have a key `g[:week_year]` this becomes

```
h[g[:week_year]] = 0 + g[:total]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) in combination with [transform_values](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Hash/transform_values):

```
array.group_by { |a| a[:week_year] }
     .transform_values { |values| values.sum { |value| value[:total] } }
```

Which will return:

```
{
 "49-2021" => 6.5,
 "45-2021" => 35.0,
 "44-2021" => 6.5,
 "46-2021" => 14.5
}
```